# How to troubleshoot Crash in App Running Android 11 (SDK 30)

Tags: android, crash, android-webview, android-11

I've never seen a stack trace like that and have no idea how to troubleshoot. It didn't happen in Android 10 (SDK 29) or earlier. The app is built with androidx support library and SDK 30.

The phone where it has happened:

```
Samsung Note 10+ 5G running on SDK 30
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

That's all I could get from PlayStore:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> app-package-name <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000038621f0  /data/app/~~dDiCj_8810kb6DPfFJq1VA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_438909034-1CcX13lT2sfyKsCGVu4mkA==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x646000)
```

Comment: Be aware that they may be possible System WebView issue: [Android apps keep crashing: Gmail, Yahoo Mail, Google app issues reported -Android System Webview-](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/mb0wy5/android_apps_keep_crashing_gmail_yahoo_mail/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) See: [Native Exception on a Pixel 2 XL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66755788/295004)

Comment: We got similar crash log and user feedback on Mar 22~23, and the crash stoped 7 hours ago, we did nothing on our App side. So it's very possible related to the WebView issue mentioned by @MorrisonChang

Comment: https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=aa75515d184a2423be444d676b7ebf45 Google fixed it. But it requires users to update their Android System WebView

Comment: @Tink - Yay, it's fixed after the update. You guys can post it as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks for all your comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google announced [an incident](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=aa75515d184a2423be444d676b7ebf45) for their own Gmail App. Users cannot launch the App. And it's related to the Android System WebView, which is more like a component for Android system but can be updated via [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview).
The issue was reported at 3/23/21, 7:05 AM
But this issue is more than Google thought. Not only Gmail app will crash, many other Apps will crash too. [Reddit thread for this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/mb0wy5/android_apps_keep_crashing_gmail_yahoo_mail/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Unluckily, our App is one of them, we saw live crash number going up and then going down. And we have many users complain about this. They just cannot open our App.

Luckily, Google fixed their bug and everything will be good if users update their Android System WebView app in Google Play.

We didn't catch this crash in Firebase Crashlytics, but we can see it in Google Play Console. And actually, I have no idea about this crash log. I have to Google it to see if it's only me or for everyone. Thanks for posting this issue here so I know I'm not alone.

Comment: Thanks for all these details. Google/Android goes down quickly as a platform. As a result - a lot of frustrated users and upset developers. I used to <3 Android, but start hating it lately.

Comment: So is there a way to prevent this from code? We have still around 3k daily users that apparently haven't heard news about the fix, nor have updated. For them our app is the one with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @Morrison Chang and @Tink have indicated in comments, the crashes have been related to Android System WebView that can be found at the following location in Play Store:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview
```

In my case the problem has been fixed after I've updated the above app with the release that Google has pushed to Play Store on 03/22.

Even though my application doesn't use WebView directly there are probably dependencies in the Android and Samsung libraries that my application relies on.